# create a loop in R to process multiples files

Tags: r, loops, readfile

I'm new using R and I have a doubt, I have this code for for una file:

```
peak <- readPeakFile("file", header=F)
peakpeakAnno <- annotatePeak(peak, tssRegion=c(-3000, 3000), TxDb=txdb, annoDb="org.Hs.eg.db")

write.table(peakAnno,"annotcaca", sep="\t", col.names=T, row.names = F)
```

I would like to know how I can create a loop that processes multiples files at the same time.

Thank you!!

Comment: Try `files <- list.files(); lapply(files, function(x) {peak <- readPeakFile(....); peakpeakAnno <- ....})`

Comment: And how I can export the write tables in two differents txt?